# Reusing an Asio connection

Tags: c++, http, tcp, boost-asio, keep-alive

I am working on a project currently where I have a web-server.  I have to add the ability so that for each request, I need to send multiple requests to other servers, get responses, and send back results to the original client.  These servers are high throughput, so I was getting worried about the number of sockets as well as the speeds of setting up new threads/sockets for sending out many requests over many sockets.  So I started thinking that have a single(or a few connections), open to each client would help solve this problem.  I wasn't sure how persistent connections and boost ASIO worked though.  Some questions I had:

-How can I set keep alive times using ASIO tcp sockets.

-Can I send out multiple concurrent requests over the same socket? Would I run into an issue with the order of the results(Each result should have an Id, so I don't mean order as in results being sent out of order, but more packet order, if a response is more than one packet, will I have a problem with the order of the packets).

All requests are HTTP GET/POST requests if that matters too.

Any information in this subject would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A TCP socket acts as a data stream, the data you write on one end will be received in the same  order in the other end. You can send multiple requests over the same socket if your protocol can handle it.

You mention concurrent requests, therefore you need to be very careful to not interleave the write calls of two different requests. If you can ensure that each result is written atomically, then I see no problem in using a socket for multiple requests (you can do that with a reply queue).

You can set the standard socket keep alive [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/keep_alive.html).

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, I was planning on using a queuing system for the write calls, so I believe this should work well for me.